# How to choose default "Open With" program without finding a file first?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, operating-systems

After an update for Windows 10 Pro, I can now no longer choose a program as the default for opening a certain type of file, but rather must choose an app from the Microsoft store. Am I doing something wrong, or is there now no way to do this from the Settings app? I am still able to set the default by locating a file and using right-click > Open With to pick a program.

EXAMPLE: I want .ANS files to always open with Notepad++.

Of course I have Notepad++ installed and functioning, but after this update, I can't just click "Choose a program" and go find the notepadplusplus.exe like I used to.

I do not want to install Microsoft's Notepad++ app for this.

[image: Choose default]

Comment: open the .ans file in Explorer with Notepad++ and tell here Windows to open it all time with Notepad++

Comment: So Microsoft intentionally made it impossible to do this starting from the Settings app?

Comment: I have no idea why Microsoft makes it so complicated. I always use the explorer/open with way

Comment: The accepted answer posted doesn't work any more on newer versions of Windows 10. I use Windows 10 20H2. Can anyone provide a working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open file explorer  and paste `C:\Windows\System32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageFileAssoc` in the bar and hit enter.

Comment: Also, you can just type that in Run without the file path `control /name...`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me as of now. It offers a very limited range of options by name ('Photo viewer') not extension, and selecting the option for file types brings me to the screen in OP where it only allows me to go to the App Store.

Comment: This doesn't work any more on newer versions of Windows 10. I use Windows 10 20H2. Can anyone provide a working solution?

Answer (score -1):

You need to right click to Open with one .ans file to choose desktop app.

[image]

After that, it will show up in settings:

[image]

Comment: So Microsoft intentionally made it impossible to do this starting from the Settings app?

Comment: Absolutely not; you can clearly see the ability to choose a default application for an extension in the screenshot

Comment: I said "starting from the Settings app", not "starting from a file's right-click menu" @Ramhound

Comment: You absolutely can find the “choose default...” from within the Settings application I just did it the other day.